# requests url encoding for multi-valued parameters

Tags: python, google-maps, python-requests

Using the requests library how can I make a multivalued int parameter?
I'm trying to give an origin to the google maps api, but can't get it to encode properly

```
start_coordinates = {'latitude':40.970321, 'longitude' :29.060873}
end_coordinates = {'latitude':41.029967, 'longitude' :28.974656}  

start_latitude = start_coordinates.get('latitude')
start_longitude = start_coordinates.get('longitude')
end_latitude = end_coordinates.get('longitude')
end_longitude = end_coordinates.get('latitude')

url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json'
params = {
    'origin' : '%s,%s' %(start_latitude,start_longitude),
    'destination' : '%s,%s' %(end_latitude, end_longitude),
    'sensor' : 'false',
    }
google_response = requests.get(url,params=params)
```

the `google_response` is:

`u'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.970321%2C29.060873&destination=28.974656%2C41.029967&sensor=false'`

but it should be :

`u'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.970321,29.060873&destination=28.974656,41.029967&sensor=false'`

where the parameters should look like `origin=40.970321,29.060873` instead of `destination=28.974656%2C41.029967`

further example :

this doesnt work :
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.970321%2C29.060873&destination=28.974656%2C41.029967&sensor=false

this works: 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.970321,29.060873&destination=41.029967,28.974656&sensor=false

---

Its obviously an error on my part it seems :

```
well this is embarrassing. It was my first few lines that threw the code off, it should be:

start_coordinates = {'latitude':40.970321, 'longitude' :29.060873}
end_coordinates = {'latitude':41.029967, 'longitude' :28.974656}
start_latitude = start_coordinates.get('latitude')
start_longitude = start_coordinates.get('longitude')
end_latitude = end_coordinates.get('latitude')
end_longitude = end_coordinates.get('longitude')


url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json'
params = {
    'origin' : '%s,%s' %(start_latitude,start_longitude),
    'destination' : '%s,%s' %(end_latitude, end_longitude),
    'sensor' : 'false',
    }
google_response = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

I got the `end_longitude` and `end_latitude` wrong. So this fixes it

Comment: Why can't the comma be encoded?

Comment: Try providing a replicable example (i.e. set the variables like start_latitude etc.)

Comment: @dorvak added a replicable example.
@MartijnPieters Its being encoded, but the encoded %2C is not being accepted from google. I get `"ZERO_RESULTS"` for status

Comment: I've mixed up the `end_latitude` and `end_longitude` when those are correct the code works. I am ashamed. and I cant answer it since my reputation is low. sorry guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on a decodec url, try this one:

```
In [54]: urllib.unquote(google_response.url).decode('utf8')
Out[54]: u'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.970321,29.060873&destination=28.974656,41.029967&sensor=false'
```

EDIT: As urllib changes the ordering (i think it's due to using a dict internally), this method doesn't work either. I'd suggest to construct the url manually, via pythons string-concatenation/formating methods.

Comment: its because of the internal dicts ordering. Thanks

Comment: Indeed. I tend to use an OrderedDict in this case (or lists or tuples).